# Implement Share App Facility in static Shortcuts

Tags: android, android-intent, share, shortcut, android-static-shortcuts

I was trying to implement "Share App" facility as App Shortcut in Android (like iOS platform). This facility must exist immediately after installing even without opening app. I want to know how I can use this intent in shortcut xml file:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://www.example.com");
        intent.setType("text/plain");
```

Comment: have u found any solution?

Comment: @kgandroid Yes I found a way to do that. you can see my answer below. I hope it helps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54881265/share-intent-option-using-shortcut-android

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any way to put `type` attribute for intent in `xml`.
But it seems an activity with invisible theme can simulate what I want.

As [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/managing-shortcuts) said:

> Start one activity from another
>
> Static shortcuts cannot have custom intent flags. The first intent of
>   a static shortcut will always have Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and
>   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK set. This means, when the app is
>   already running, all the existing activities in your app are destroyed
>   when a static shortcut is launched. If this behavior is not desirable,
>   you can use a trampoline activity, or an invisible activity that
>   starts another activity in Activity.onCreate(Bundle), then calls
>   Activity.finish():
>
> In the AndroidManifest.xml file, the trampoline activity should
>   include the attribute assignment android:taskAffinity="". In the
>   shortcuts resource file, the intent within the static shortcut should
>   reference the trampoline activity. For more information about
>   trampoline activities, read Start one activity from another.

we can add `android:taskAffinity=""` to the InvisibleActivity in `manifest` file to prevent the app from going to background when home button clicked.

This is my invisible activity setup in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
    android:name=".InvisibleActivity"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:taskAffinity=""
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```

This is the whole `onCreate()` method in my invisible activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://www.example.com");
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
    finish();
}
```

and finally this is my static shortcut xml file:

```
<shortcut
    android:enabled="true"
    android:shortcutId="share_app_shortcut"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
    android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/shortcut_share_description">

    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetClass=".InvisibleActivity"
        android:targetPackage="com.example.shortcut">
    </intent>

</shortcut>
```

Comment: You will face the issue of android system or the app will be going to background when the user clicks on the home button.This should not happen.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54881265/share-intent-option-using-shortcut-android

Comment: @kgandroid Thanks for your bug report. I edited the solution. hope it helps.