# Share intent option using Shortcut android

Tags: android, android-shortcut

By default iOS is providing **"Share appname"** option in the shortcut options,when the app is downloaded from the app store.

**Refer the image below:**

[image]

When clicked on it,**it is opening the share intent in the phone menu screen itself**,without redirecting to the app,where the user can share the app.

[image]

**I want to implement this in android**.

Here is what I have I tried so far:

```
<shortcut
        android:shortcutId="share_app"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_cart_active"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/shortcut_share"
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/shortcut_share">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.send"
            android:targetPackage="com.example.android.internal"
            android:targetClass="" />
    </shortcut>
```

But this is not working,since I am not able to understand, what should be the 
**targetClass** over here.

**EDIT:** Nilesh`s answer almost worked,but the only problem that I am facing right now is,whenever I am clicking the share button from shortcut, the launcher activity is shown for a whisker of a second ,then the sharing intent chooser is showing up.Now when I am pressing the home button with the sharing options showing,the app is going to background.This should not happen.Any idea how to avoid this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`App shortcuts`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html#pinning)

but the main disadavtange of this option  is that it is  available from Oreo and above version of android

Here is the sample code

> Create a resource file: **`res/xml`** directory (**[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTtFR.png)**)

```
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shortcut
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
        android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/share_app"
        android:shortcutId="nilu"
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/share_app"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/share_app">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetClass="neel.com.demo.ShareActivity"
            android:targetPackage="neel.com.demo" />
        <categories android:name="android.shortcut.conversation" />
    </shortcut>
</shortcuts>
```

> Now you need to register your shortcut in your manifest file under activity tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="neel.com.demo">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />

        <activity android:name=".ShareActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
                android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

> Now create a simple share acivity to share your app link

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class ShareActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                "Hey check out my app at: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=neel.com.demo");
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(sendIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

When user long press on app icon your shortcut will display like below image

[image]

after click of shortcut

[image]

**UPDATE** use **`android:excludeFromRecents="true"`** in your `ShareActivity`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ShareActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
            android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />

    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Let me implement this and will let you know.BDW this is what I want

Comment: @kgandroid happy to hear you that let me know if any help required

Comment: Do I really need to give setContentView(R.layout.activity_home); in the Activity?

Comment: I have already another activity defined as launcher in Manifest.xml

Comment: @kgandroid no need to define share activity as defined as launcher

Comment: One more thing,If I click on the home button with sharing intent open,then the app is appearing in the background.Any way to avoid that.In ios this is not happening

Comment: @NileshRathod looks good; just wouldn't show the uninstall button on the home-screen; that's bad for user retention and/or accidental clicks & pocket dialing... and shortcuts need an API level check, for the backwards compatibility.

Comment: @MartinZeitler `just wouldn't show the uninstall button on the home-screen` that's system added sort cut on app icon so we can't control it and for `shortcuts need an API level check, for the backwards compatibility` it will work on android oreo version and above i have tested in Oreo and its working fine and also no other issue in marshmallow

Comment: @NileshRathod that might be the dynamic shortcuts then. might have confused that. however, those dynamic shortcut menus do not have the uninstall button. that's a huge difference, besides how they are being generated (which ordinary is something the users doesn't care much - unless one permits their configuration). the static `XML` shortcuts still appear to be the direct equivalent to the Apple shortcuts.

Comment: The only problem that I am facing right now is,whenever I am clicking the share button the launcher activity is shown for a whisker of a second ,then the sharing intent is showing up.Now when I am pressing the home button in that state,the app is going to background.This should not happen.Any idea how to avoid this?

Comment: Hi Nilesh,Thanks for your effort and time.Additionally I have added some extra flags to the ShareActivity to make it work as expected: sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);

Comment: Also in the manifest: <activity
            android:name=".util.ShareActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        </activity>

Comment: @kgandroid happy to hear that

Answer (score 0):

there is two way to create shortcut.

**one:** create static shortcuts,In your app's manifest file (AndroidManifest.xml), find an activity whose intent filters are set to the android.intent.action.MAIN action and the android.intent.category.LAUNCHER category. and then add a  element to this activity that references the resource file where the app's shortcuts are defined:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.myapplication">
<application ... >
<activity android:name="Main">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>

  <meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
             android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" /> 
</activity>
```

...

**two**:Create dynamic shortcuts
you can use code to do it,The ShortcutManager API allows you to complete the following operations on dynamic shortcuts:

```
ShortcutManager shortcutManager = getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);

ShortcutInfo shortcut = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(context, "id1")
.setShortLabel("Website")
.setLongLabel("Open the website")
.setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(context, R.drawable.icon_website))
.setIntent(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
               Uri.parse("https://www.mysite.example.com/")))
.build();

shortcutManager.setDynamicShortcuts(Arrays.asList(shortcut));
```

for more information, you can through the official website [how to create shortcut in android?](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts#java)

Comment: I know how to create a shortcut.I need to create a shortcut that shares my app without launching it,just like ios